# Can not insert null object on One to One relation Spring boot | nested exception is .PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

This is the relation

```
   @OneToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST )
    @JoinColumn(name = "ALL_ORG_MST_ORGANIZATION_ID")
    private AllOrgMst allOrgMstOrganizationId;
```

And postman Object Data

```
{
    "empSts": "Active",
    "empRef": null,
    "probationDuration": "6",
    "allOrgMstGroupId": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "allOrgMstOrganizationId": {
        "id": null
    }
}
```

I can not insert null value .If I give the AllOrgMstOrganizationId then no problem.But when I give it Null Then
Error::org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.hrms.entity.com.AllOrgMst; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.hrms.entity.com.AllOrgMst

Comment: Are you trying to merge or persist? Can you update your question with the em operation you are trying to do?

Comment: @Rakib
Yes I am trying merge or persis same error

Comment: @Rakib
Error::org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing :

Comment: @Rakib
https://pastebin.com/PUqsEk5f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Solutions

```
{
    "empSts": "Active",
    "empRef": null,
    "probationDuration": "6",
    "allOrgMstGroupId": {
        "id": 1
    }, 
    "allOrgMstOrganizationId": null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the value of field `allOrgMstOrganizationId` from empty object to `null`. Maybe this will solve your problem. The dataset be like bellow:

```
{
    "empSts": "Active",
    "empRef": null,
    "probationDuration": "6",
    "allOrgMstGroupId": {
        "id": 1
    }, 
    "allOrgMstOrganizationId": null
}
```